# Assessing Differences in Survival with a Multi-Level Categorical Variable

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, proportional-hazards

I would like to check if my overall survival differs be a multi-level categorical variable. I have 300 subjects and 15 levels. Is KM log-rank the most appropriate test?

If so, how do I check the PH hazards assumption with a variable with so many levels?

I know that the log-rank test does not rely on PH, but it would be most powerful in the case of PH so I still want to check it.